# Limechat Sticky Sessions

Tags: macos

Is there a way to have Limechat "stickily" joined into a network+room(s)?

My laptop sleeps, and it takes the connection with it. I need to go through the motions of "Connect" to the network and then "Join" a room 12 times an hour.

I'd like to "Join and forget..." where connection stability does not dictate access to the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running a bouncer like ZNC http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC somewhere, or using a paid service that does the same. I use ZNC on a Mac mini at home and it keeps me logged into IRC and sends me a push notification when my nick is mentioned. Great way to stay on IRC.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'll try it out, thanks!